# Ejecutar una función de javascript dentro de código PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema al intentar llamar a una función *javascript* desde un código *php*:

Tengo la siguiente función dentro de un archivo scripts.js:

```js
function openPage(url) {
    if(url.indexOf("?") == -1) {
        url = url + "?";
    }
    var encodedUrl = encodeURI(url + "&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn);
    $("#mainContent").load(encodedUrl);
    //'scrollTop' al cargarse una nueva pagina
    $("body").scrollTop(0);
    history.pushState(null, null, url);
}
```

Esta función se debe ejecutar cuando el usuario inserta manualmente una url.
La función la ejecuto dentro de este archivo php:

```js
<?php

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) {
    include 'includes/config.php';
    include 'classes/Artist.php';
    include 'classes/Album.php';
    include 'classes/Song.php';
} else {
    include 'includes/header.php';
    include 'includes/footer.php';

    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    echo "<script> openPage('$url') </script>";
    exit();
}

?>
```

Ya he intentado usar todas las combinaciones de comillas posibles. También he intentado escapar las comillas **(\")** y revisado en varios foros las posibles soluciones pero sigo sin ver el error. Al hacer una inspección de los elementos veo lo siguiente:

```html
<div id="mainContainer">...</div>
"


 openPage('/proyecto-rockify/album_php?id=4') "
  </body>
</html>
```

¿Dónde puede estar el fallo?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: En que el código javascript no se ejecuta del lado del servidor sino del lado del cliente? Podrías considerar hacer una llamada con AJAX desde el cliente hacia un script PHP que tenga esa función, si es lo que necesitas.

Comment: Ok. He usado haciendo la llamada de función con AJAX y funciona bien. La duda era porque revisando proyectos parecidos no hacian la llamada a ajax para esa función y aún así funcionaba haciendo echo desde el archivo php. Muchas gracias. @eftshift0

Answer (score 0):

Aunque lo he podido solucionar usando una llamada Ajax, también he logrado que funcione de la manera planteada en el problema. El fallo estaba en la etiqueta de cierre del documento html, la cuál estaba mal cerrada. Ahora aya sê que funciona de las dos formas, una con Ajax y otra incluyendo el script en un archivo php y haciendo echo de esa función :).